# How to join tables to subquery results in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following query:

```
SELECT customer_id, product_id, COUNT(product_id) CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_COUNT
  2  FROM Order_Details
  3  Group BY customer_id, product_id
  4  HAVING COUNT(product_id) > 1;
```

which results in following table:

```
CUSTOMER_ID PRODUCT_ID CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_COUNT
---------- ---------- ----------------------
C1         P3                              2
```

I am trying to use this as a subquery to join the customer_ID to customer_name from Customer table. The product_id column is also present in another table named Order_Details which I am also trying to join so that it gives address of the customer:

So far I've come up with following query which gives an error:

```
SELECT c.customer_name, a.country, a.zone, a.district, a.city
  2  FROM (
  3     SELECT customer_id, product_id, COUNT(product_id) CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_COUNT
  4     FROM Order_Details
  5     Group BY customer_id, product_id
  6     HAVING COUNT(product_id) > 1) AS o
  7  JOIN Customer c ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
  8  JOIN Address a ON a.address_id = o.address_id;
```

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended, is the error and it highlights AS o for the initiation of error

Answer (score 1):

This query looks correct:

```
SELECT c.customer_name, a.country, a.zone, a.district, a.city
FROM (SELECT customer_id, product_id, COUNT(product_id) CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_COUNT
      FROM Order_Details
      GROUP BY customer_id, product_id
      HAVING COUNT(product_id) > 1
     ) AS o JOIN
     Customer c
     ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id JOIN
     Address a
     ON a.address_id = o.address_id;
```

Apart from the reference to `o.address_id` which I would guess is intended as `c.address_id`, I can only think of two possible problems:

- The column references are not correct.
- You are using Oracle, which doesn't allow `as` in the `FROM` clause.

In any case, I would write the query like this:

```
SELECT c.customer_name, a.country, a.zone, a.district, a.city
FROM (SELECT customer_id, product_id, COUNT(*) as CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_COUNT
      FROM Order_Details od
      GROUP BY customer_id, product_id
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) o JOIN
     Customer c
     ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id JOIN
     Address a
     ON a.address_id = c.address_id;
```

There is no need to count the non-NULL`values in a column when you simply want to count rows.  That is what`COUNT(*)` does.

Comment: I am indeed using Oracle, but still it gives an error: ERROR at line 10:
ORA-00904: "O"."ADDRESS_ID": invalid identifier

Comment: @SamitPaudel . . . I think you intend `c.address_id`.

Comment: Yes ERROR at line 10:
ORA-00904: "C"."ADDRESS_ID": invalid identifier